# Compare strings which contains random number

Tags: php

I need to make a function in PHP which will check, when someone submits a button, if string is present with generated random number.
The string will be always the same but number inside string will be always different.

Example strings:

- Heloo 123120510 how are you?
- Heloo 12355 how are you?
- Heloo 0510 how are you?
- Heloo 1231205103242 how are you?

I need to write a test if this string is shown once button is submitted. How my regex for checking the number should look like?

```
if(buttonSubmitted()){
    if($currentString == "Heloo !probablySomeRegex! how are you?"){
        return TRUE
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
```

If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance

Comment: Care to explain minus point?

Comment: The question of comments + downvotes has been discussed ad nauseum on Meta. Many folks just choose to DV and move on. Many offer advice. Many try to light the path for newbies.

Comment: " if string is present" - presented where?

Comment: Jay, some times people are just like: *I don't know how to do that stuff... ***downvote**** it's so unclear to me.*

Comment: True @PhiterFernandes and that has also been discussed on Meta until the dead horse nearly rose back to life. But here I am thinking the DV is because the OP showed no effort whatsoever, they just want someone to write their regex for them. Oh look! Someone has done just that!

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest
Sorry for bad english. I will write a test which check if this string is present, so you don't have to worry about that. I just need to know how to write that function to compare current string with other string

Comment: I know, this question is really too broad. But what I pointed out happens sometimes unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
if (preg_match('/Heloo \d+ how are you\?/im', $subject)) {
    return TRUE;
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

---

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP0nG6/1)

---

**Regex Explanation:**

```
Heloo \d+ how are you\?/mi

    Heloo matches the characters Heloo literally (case insensitive)
    \d+ match a digit [0-9]
        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
     how are you matches the characters  how are you literally (case insensitive)
    \? matches the character ? literally
    m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
    i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard Regex101 Demo link is present on the answer, still, I've updated my answer with a regex explanation.

Comment: Good - because if Regex101 went away the explanation - although wrong, would be here. PHP has no `g` modifier.

Comment: The original regex was correct, only regex101 explanation was wrong, updated now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
if(buttonSubmitted()){
    if(preg_match('/^Heloo \d+ how are you\?$/', $currentString)){
        return TRUE
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** 
It is case sensitive. It will check for "Heloo " after that any number combinations then " how are you?"

Answer (score 1):

I tend to prefer to stay away from Regex but if I was to make my own method of doing this I'd do it this way.

```
// If you know that the string is going to  be the same structure.
function getNumberInString($string) {
  return explode(' ', $string)[1];
}

// If you don't know where the number will occur in the string.
function getNumberInString($string) {
  // Loops each piece of the sentence and returns the number if there is a number.
  foreach (explode(' ', $string) as $piece) {
    if (is_numeric($piece) ) return $piece;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Hope this helps :)
This answer should do what you want, being that the string is **exactly** the same each time, the first one will help quickly and easily.